# Sum of exponentials

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

**Question:** Does there exists $t\in \mathbb{R}$ such that the sum below holds true?
$$\sum_{n=1}^N a_ne^{ib_nt}=0$$
where $a_n\in\mathbb{C}$ and $b_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer could be either yes or no, depending on which linear combination it is.

Think of it this way.  The equation is equivalent to
$$ a_N = - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} a_n e^{i(b_n-b_N)t} $$

Given $b_1, \ldots, b_N$ and $a_1, \ldots, a_{N-1}$, the right side is either
a constant or describes a curve in the complex plane; in any case, a set of
two-dimensional Lebesgue measure $0$.  So for almost every $a_N \in \mathbb C$, there will be no real solution $t$, but for those $a_N$ that happen to be on the curve there will be a solution.

Comment: Just a minor addendum. If $p(x)=x\cdot\prod_{j=1}^{N-1}(x-\xi_j)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}a_n x^n$ and $\|\xi_j\|\neq 1$, $$\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n e^{it}\neq 0.$$

Comment: You mean $\sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n e^{int}$.

Comment: $\phantom{}$ Oh, yes, sure.